# Can "dressing" a qubit multiple times increase the dephasing time more than dressing it once?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-information, quantum-computer

A paper was recently published ([arXiv pre-publication link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.04800v1.pdf); I've only read a more popular description of the content because of my lack of domain knowledge) describing how "dressing" a qubit in a microwave field consistently resulted in a roughly tenfold increase in the longevity of a usable signal-to-noise ratio of the qubit.

I'm not an expert in the field, but my takeaway is that by keeping a qubit suspended in an oscillating electromagnetic field, less noise could affect the qubit, preserving its signal for much longer without corruption.

Considering the results were so beneficial, is there any way to use multiple electromagnetic fields to "stack" this effect, increasing usable signal-to-noise lifetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can. In particular, dressing an already dressed qubit can protect from the decoherence introduced by fluctuations of the microwave field used for the (first) dressing.

This is, eg, described here:
http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/14/11/113023

> The principal idea of CCD is to provide a concatenated set of continuous driving fields with decreasing intensities (and thus smaller absolute value of fluctuation) such that each new driving field protects against the fluctuations of the driving field at the preceding level.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and thanks for providing a reliable and open source!